# what's the compression config in kafka new version (>=0.11)

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 0.11, I'd like to compress the message under a specific topic,but the old config parameters were obsoleted: `compression.codec and compressed.topics`.

I found the new version compress config called: `compression.type`. But how can I set the topic parameter, since I just want to compress one topic. And how can I know the compression is working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the compression at topic level , please refer to 
[Topic level config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs)

For verification , you can check the size of compressed msg by consuming it or checking the file size on disk